# How to import bootstrap-select in bootstrap version 5?

Tags: bootstrap-5, bootstrap-select

I want to create a simple select option with `bootstrap-select.  I'm using bootstrap-select to create my select picker.

I see this error in the console

[image: error]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fa" dir="rtl">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
    <title>مدیریت</title>
    <style>
        * {
            font-family: Tahoma;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="lang">زبان</label>
                <select id="lang" name="lang" class="form-control">
                    <option value="1">فارسی</option>
                    <option value="2">عربی</option>
                    <option value="3">انگلیسی</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/js/i18n/defaults-*.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#lang').selectpicker();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do any of these answers satisfy your question?  If not can you elaborate why not so we can best assist you on this somewhat older question?

Answer (score 15):

This plug-in has been updated to support Bootstrap 5+
I informally (very basic) tested this using Bootstrap 5.1.3 and it seems to work find in that preliminary test

- Bootstrap 5 is now supported in v1.14.0-beta2 (2021-03-25) +

Sample with bootstrap 5.2 using the beta

```css
    * {
      font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fa" dir="rtl">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-iYQeCzEYFbKjA/T2uDLTpkwGzCiq6soy8tYaI1GyVh/UjpbCx/TYkiZhlZB6+fzT" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.14.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
  <title>Languages</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="lang">Language</label>
          <select id="lang" name="lang" class="form-control">
            <option value="1">English</option>
            <option value="2">French</option>
            <option value="3">Kiswahili</option>
            <option value="3">Diné bizaad</option>
            <option value="3">Oneida</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-u1OknCvxWvY5kfmNBILK2hRnQC3Pr17a+RTT6rIHI7NnikvbZlHgTPOOmMi466C8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.14.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.14.0-beta3/dist/js/i18n/defaults-*.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $('#lang').selectpicker();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you send the test that works? I cannot make Bootstrap 5 to work with `bootstrap-select`, but version 4.

Comment: @timo - I don't understand your comment with the "I cannot make Bootstrap 5 to work with bootstrap-select, but version 4"  This question is about Bootstrap 5, do you need to ask a question re: Bootstrap 4 or are you saying you continue to have a challenge with Bootstrap 5? Either way, seems like a NEW question where you need to provide your details on your implementation perhaps.

Comment: I updated with a beta example snippet

Comment: I'm still having issues: "ReferenceError: bootstrap is not defined"

Comment: @ArtFranco  I have no reference for this comment; perhaps you can ask a new question with all your details and a reproducible example?

Answer (score 5):

bootstrap-select for Bootstrap 5 is still under development.  See https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/tree/v1.14-dev for current versions.

Comment: It's not under active development anymore, but [this might help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77625822/1529709).

Answer (score 1):

In December of 2023, [this project is officially orphaned](https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/issues/2228#issuecomment-1236207188) for over a year now.

> Unfortunately, it seems developments on this project have come to a
> halt. I tried to impulse a new dynamic but without success to be
> honest.

Current [HEAD stands at v1.14.0-beta3](https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md) - But this version caused various troubles for me when upgrading a web application from Bootstrap 3 to 5.

However, [a kind soul](https://github.com/mattymatty76) has [provided some more fixes](https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/issues/2837) and dubbed this [v1.14.0-gamma1](https://gist.github.com/mattymatty76/c996d3b77f298b2ec133be59992df9d4).

In my case this solved enough problems to avoid replacing the lib with something else.

Answer (score 0):

bootstrap-select.js needs to update for compatible to bootstrap@5+

- edit bootstrap-select.js and change data-toggle attribute into data-bs-toggle