# bootstrap-select not working together with bootstrap 5

Tags: bootstrap-5, bootstrap-select

I am using the library [bootstrap-select](https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select), recently I needed to upgrade from bootstrap version 4 to 5, according to the bootstrap-select side there should be support and no issue with that.

Here is a link zu the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mw6j9Lkt/)

[image]

This is what I m trying to do, and it worked before the upgrade:

```
const inputScreen = $('<select class="selectpicker"><option>test</option></select>').appendTo(conScreen);
inputScreen.selectpicker();
```

However, the dropdown elements are being shown, but I cant open it.

[image]

There is no error in the console. The only thing i can see, is that there is an hidden element which never gots displayed:
[image]

Comment: Please include an [mcve] with your question.  It makes it easier for everyone to troubleshoot and you'll get a faster answer ;)

Comment: you are right, i added a jsFiddle link at the top

Comment: Doesn't appear accurate stating "Now with Bootstrap 5 support". The official site page states v.4 and all the other text, within the GitHub page, refers to v.4 as well....besides that animated image you added as a screenshot.
Unless, one installs the latest beta version 1.14.0-beta2;  e.g. via NuGet within visual studio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i figgured the answer out myself, it is about the position of the include. Popper.js needs to be included before bootstrap v5. That did the job!

Answer (score 3):

for solve this problem, we cane use beta3 version
https://openbase.com/js/bootstrap-select/versions

Comment: it's still strange that there is only a beta working. Bootstrap 5 is already there for a long time

Comment: Although bootstrap-select seems to be a dead project, there's an [unofficial version which works quite well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67643806/how-to-import-bootstrap-select-in-bootstrap-version-5/77625822#77625822) with Bootstrap 5.x.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, solved it by downgrading bootstrap to version 4.6.1

Answer (score 0):

You can use min version for all javascript and css libraries. It worked for me.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap-select/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" />
  </head>

  <body>

    <!-- Your page code is here -->

    <script src="~/lib/jquery/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/popper.js/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap-select/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The libraries versions:

```json
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "defaultProvider": "cdnjs",
  "libraries": [
    {
      "library": "bootstrap@5.2.1",
      "destination": "wwwroot/lib/bootstrap/"
    },
    {
      "library": "bootstrap-select@1.13.18",
      "destination": "wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-select/"
    },
    {
      "provider": "cdnjs",
      "library": "jquery@3.6.1",
      "destination": "wwwroot/lib/jquery/"
    },
    {
      "provider": "cdnjs",
      "library": "popper.js@2.11.6",
      "destination": "wwwroot/lib/popper.js/"
    }
  ]
}
```