# Bootstrap-select is not working with Bootstrap 5

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I followed the Getting Started guide [from their official webpage](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/)

I added the JS and CSS libraries to my project and it does not work.

For some reason `selectpicker` is set to `display: none!important`:

[image]

```
    .bootstrap-select>select.bs-select-hidden, select.bs-select-hidden, select.selectpicker {
        display: none!important;
    }
```

And I am getting this error:

[image]

Caused by this JS:
`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>`

What I've tried:

- Even if I change the code to `display: block` bootstrap-select it is still not working.
- Changing the order of the imports as suggested in another SO question

I already checked [this previous SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67828362/bootstrap-select-not-working-together-with-bootstrap-5) question and I changed the order of the imports but still, it is not working.

[JS FIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/gerasg/56gq1kvp/9/)

Comment: jsfiddle shows "Script error." in console

Comment: And this is the js causing the error: `<!-- Bootstrap Select JS -->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>` what can I do?

Comment: why u tag twitter-bootstrap but you are not using it

Comment: Because `bootstrap-select` is an extension of bootstrap itself. I am using it in my project just the sample code is truncated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solved, apparently the version I was using is not compatible with BS5

What I did:

`script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.14.0-beta2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>`

Use version `1.14.0-beta2` instead of `1.13.14`

Comment: The beta versions didn't cut it for me, but there's a [slightly better, unofficial version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77625822/1529709) out there.